# JSON Validator in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, json

I am trying to get my hands on some JSON file validators.

I came across `jq` but after running `jq . file.json` I only got JSON formatted output, not a validation of the JSON in my file.

I want to know how I can check the syntax or validate JSON format in my file in Ubuntu. Please advise!

Answer (score 21):

Try `jsonlint`:

```
sudo apt install jsonlint
```

The basic usage syntax is

```
jsonlint YOUR-FILE.JSON
```

You find its manual by typing `man jsonlint` or visiting its [online manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/jsonlint.1.html):

An excerpt:

```
NAME
       jsonlint - A JSON syntax validator and formatter tool

SYNOPSIS
       jsonlint [-v][-s|-S][-f|-F][-ecodec]inputfile.json...

[...]

OPTIONS
       The  return  status  will  be  0 if the file is legal JSON, or non-zero
       otherwise.  Use -v to see the warning details.

       [...]

       -v, --verbose
              Show details of lint checking
       -s, --strict
              Be strict in what is considered legal JSON (the default)
       -S, --nonstrict
              Be loose in what is considered legal JSON
       -f, --format
              Reformat the JSON (if legal) to stdout

[...]
```

So you can see whether your JSON is valid by checking the return code of `jsonlint`. You can see it by running `echo $?` right afterwards (0=OK, 1=invalid), or by evaluating it using `&&`, `||` or `if`.

Comment: What exactly jsonlint will do, please advise

Comment: When I installed the `jsonlint` package on Ubuntu just now, the installed binary was for some reason called `jsonlint-php` rather than `jsonlint`.  It appears to work correctly, but I had to remember the `dpkg-query -L` command to figure out what it had actually installed.

Comment: It installed as `jsonlint-php` for me as well. Also, the call it expects is a little unusual, with the commands at the end. You use `jsonlint-php file.json -v` for verbose outputs, for example.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Note that you can type `jsonlint+<tab>` and it will finish and add the `-php` for you.

Answer (score 10):

I tried `jsonlint` but it doesn't work.

`jq . may-file.json` work nice!

Hope this feedback is helpful.

Comment: Note: to install `jsonlint` you need to run `sudo apt install jsonlint`, but to run the program itself, the usage is: `jsonlint-php <file.json>`

Comment: Thank you, but : When you install `jsonlint` you install all this dependencies 
`php-cli php-common php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline` (maybe `php-pear` too) and you need to get **2,519 kB**
, when you install `jq` you install this dependencies `libjq1 libonig4` and you need to get **276 kB**.

Each one has its own preferences :)

Comment: Recommending `jq` over `jsonlint` for large JSON files. It was more than 10× faster reading, analyzing and prettyprinting a 600 MiB JSON file in my test.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using python `json.tool` module

`echo '{"name": "dedunu", "country": "LKA"}' | python -m json.tool`

If you have a file you can use it as below.

`python -m json.tool file.json`

But the problem with this command is that you won't get a detail about the problem in JSON file. I found the answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json).

Comment: Looks like `json.tool` will return an error code of `0` if the file is valid JSON and `1` for invalid JSON.  If you want to not print the output, the easiest way I know is to use `/dev/null` as the output.

Answer (score 4):

`jq` will spit out the error explicitly, and you can also check the exit status, which is `1` for parse errors, and obviously `0` for successes.

For example:

```
% jq '.' <<<'{"foo": "spam", "bar": 1}'
{
  "bar": 1,
  "foo": "spam"
}

% echo $?
0
```

Now, let's replace `:` with `=` after `"bar"`-- making the input an invalid `json`:

```
% jq '.' <<<'{"foo": "spam", "bar"= 1}'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 23

% echo $?                                  
1
```

Comment: But `jq` doesn't detect this incomplete document `jq '.' <<<'{"foo'`

Comment: @Joe It's not showing anything on output expectedly. Did you mean, it should raise an error or something instead?

Comment: Yes.  jsonlint (the javascript version available at jsonlint.com), for example, reports an error for that incomplete document.

Comment: jq sucks, a valid json file will report "jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:"

Comment: It says: `Input error: Is a directory` when I run `jq . package.json`. Is it a normal behavior?